# Volley json array request gives error

Tags: android, json, android-volley

My problem is related with JsonArrayRequest. I do request but it gives error. How? I created Toast, there I see that it gives error. I cannot fix it. Before I used JsonObjectRequest succesfully.
So, here is my json:

```
[
{
"name" : "Chingiz Huseynzade",
"email" : "bla@bla.bla",
"phone" : {
    "home" : "08947 000000",
    "mobile" : "9999999999"
}
},
{
"name" : "Someone",
"email" : "tommy@gmail.com",
"phone" : {
    "home" : "08946 000000",
    "mobile" : "0000000000"
}
}]
```

And here my code:

```
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = jo.getString("name");
                            //PopularBooksImageAdapter.images.add(name);
                            System.out.println(name); //for test
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    rq.add(arrayreq);
```

Comment: There array returned from you server has exactly 5 elements? To be safe you should iterate up to `response.length()` instead of 5.

Comment: yeap, I know. Why I use 5 beacuse I need only 5 of them. So I changed it to check whether it affected to my problem or not, and result is [not solved]

Comment: Well your server is probably sending a 400 or 500 http status, have you checked that? Try using a logger that logs the entire http response.

Comment: Was your error solved?

Comment: of course, approximately 380 days ago :)

Comment: you should try putting in the answer to help people with the same problem